# Is Spice the same as spaceship fuel?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, solo-a-star-wars-story

In Star Wars Kessel is known for its spice mines. I had assumed that Star Wars spice was similar to spice in Dune or was some kind of space-heroin.

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story* They go to Kessel to retrieve some of that spaceship fuel. I remember hearing a line that refers to the spaceship fuel as spice.

I saw the film yesterday and I came out with the impression that spice and coaxium are the same thing. Am I crazy?

Comment: I haven't seen the film yet, but is the legendary 12 parsec Kessel run depicted?

Comment: @DukeZhou - Yes, and they finally address the fact that it's a measure of distance after getting grief about it for 40 years.

Comment: And there is a scene where han sees some aliens of the same species as Greedo, stops the millennium falcon in mid hyperdrive, parks, gets out, and murders them. He screams that he loves killing Rhodians , even without provocation, and starts jumping up and down like a sand person until Chewbacca drags him back on board before the imperials catch up with them.

Comment: I believe they mine both--the coaxium deepest in the mines. The line you likely recall was when Qi'ra offered to trade "her slaves" for Kessel's spice, which is in all likelihood a more common trade (if Kessel has a monopoly on coaxium mining, they're not going to trade with any random person who comes by).

Answer (score 5):

A quick comparison of the canon listing for both "spice" and "coaxium" on Wookiepedia confirms that they are not the same thing. In canon, spice is a narcotic, and there are several types, but all are meant for human consumption.

Coaxium only appears in the new Han Solo movie and upcoming book, and by all descriptions is completely different.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coaxium

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Spice